# Consume 12v to 5v converter

Tags: converter, switching

I am not a genius in eletronics but I know some information about converting 12v to 5v. There are different devices that can do these stuff like linear or switching converter, and I read that switching converter is the best one.

Now, my problem is to understand what is my relation between device using 5V@300ma from a 12v battery that has the capacity of 100Ah.
How do I calculate the life time of my battery? I am very confused even because I got a very big battery (100Ah) that should run my Raspberry Pi for a while ( hopefully over a month ) but not sure.

I got a  HKU5 5V/5A UBEC from hobbyking that converts from 12v to 5v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A switching converter is not the best one for every application, for yours it probably is though.

To calculate the battery lifetime, you need to calculate the current which is drawn from the battery.

A switchmode converter will transfer the power with a certain efficiency, which is sadly not given for that device, so I'll assume some bad numbers.

$$P_{in} = \frac{P_{out}}{\eta} = \frac{5V*300mA}{0.7} \approx 2.2W $$

Even a bad switchmode power supply should be able to get 70% efficiency. So the power supplied by the battery is 2.2W, but you have the capacity in amperehours, so you'll need the current. The power supplied is constant, so the worst case current draw (highest) occurs when battery voltage is lowest. For a standard 12V battery it's nearly empty at 11V, so I'll use that.

$$I_{bat} = \frac{2.2W}{11V} = 0.2A$$

With that you can get the hours the battery will be able to supply the current:

$$\frac{100Ah}{0.2A} = 500 h \approx 21 days$$

It will probably run longer than that, as this is basically a worst case view on this, but there is some data missing to give a better estimate.

You should also be aware, that the output voltage ripple might be too high for your system to tolerate depending on how good that switch mode supply is.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful, also I got a solar panel so should be fine

Answer (score 2):

Normally one would just divide the Ah capacity of the battery by the current requirement, and get a figure in hours.

However here it is a little more complicated because you have two different voltages.  So we'll use watt hours instead.

$$100\ Ah * 12v = 1200\ Wh$$

The requirements of the Raspberry Pi are:

$$5v * 0.3\ mA = 1.5\ W$$

So the amount of time the Raspberry Pi can run is:

$$1200\ Wh / 1.5 W = 800\ hours$$

You can't really drain the battery all the way to 0 so let's say 750 hours.  Furthermore, there will be some loss in the switching regulator, let's assume it has an efficiency of 90%.  So

$$750 * 90\% = 675\ hours$$

$$675 / 24 = 28\ days$$

almost what you were hoping for.

Comment: @max246 It's interesting that the three answers (so far) all used different methods to come up with the answer, but the number of days were fairly close to each other.  So you have some confidence that you will get somewhere from three to five weeks out of your battery (and not say, three days or three months).

Comment: I have a solar panel that charge the battery when the sun is out. But it can happen 2-3 days of clouds so I wanted to make sure that my theory was right.
You guys are super good =)

Answer (score 2):

The battery rating is 12V 100Ah. So total energy the battery can deliver at 12V:
$$E_{tot} = 12 \times 100 \times 60 \times 60 \ J$$

Now the 5V, 300mA device will be consuming \$5\times .3\ Joules\$ per second.

So If we are connecting this battery and device with an ideal 12V-to-5V converter in between then the battery backup will be = total energy/energy consumption per seconds.

$$t = \frac{12 \times 100 \times 60 \times 60}{5\times 0.3} = 800\ hours \approx 33\ days$$

But practically the values can change because

1. The converter will have losses inside it
2. The converter may give 5V output even if the terminal voltage of battery falls below 12V also.